# Does anyone know if iOS has an option to add this feature where on the top of your view there is this rounded gray view?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

It's a bar that looks like the home indicator on the bottom of apps that shows on iPhone X. The *1st* image is from the clock app. The *2nd* image is from facebook, and the *3rd* image is just something I made on my own from scratch. I would like to know if I have to reinvent the wheel every time I do this like I just did? Or is there something I can use like a sub class?

Here’s an image to get a better understanding of the rounded gray view I'm talking about:

[image]

I tried looking around the home indicator if I could subclass it or something. I also tried looking around the segmented control but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no default view built into Swift to get that. But it is extremely easy to create that gray view. I wrote this code just now and should work:

```
var grayView = UIView()
grayView.frame = CGRect(x: 187, y: 100, width: 50, height: 15)
grayView.layer.maskToBounds = true
grayView.layer.cornerRadius = grayView.frame.height/2
grayView.backgroundColor = .gray

view.addSubview(grayView)
```

Answer (score 1):

This indicator looks like a very simple custom View, I think there is absolutely no need to build a wheel

Answer (score 1):

The other approach is to use a `CAShapeLayer`:

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 180, y: 100))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 220, y: 100))

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 15
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```